# Printf of an object with integer members

Tags: c++, printf

I have these strange behaviour.
If I use the code below

```
class Simple
{
public:
    Simple()
    {
        m = 1;
        mm = 2;
        mmm = 3;
    }

    ~Simple()
    {
    }

private:
    int mmm;
    int mm;
    int m;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Simple sim;

    printf("%d\n", sim);
}
```

I Have as result of the printf the number "3".
If I put in the declaration as first, for example, the variable "mm" and not "mmm", I have as result of the printf the number "2". 
Same behaviour if I put in the declaration as first the variable "m", printf give me "1".
Seems that printf can print the first int variable declared. How is possible?

Comment: As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Keep in mind that when people write "undefined behavior" that means the programming language does not have a standard behavior for the expression yuo are studying. That means each compiler vendor gets to decide how to handle it.

Comment: @nicomp The compiler doesn't have to decide how to handle it. They can simply assume UB never happens because they don't have to care about whatever happens when there is UB.

Comment: Anything is possible with undefined behavior, so you'll have to get used to it. C++ and C are designed to be efficient, so in many cases, it is assumed that you know what you're doing and there aren't error checks build in for you. When you cause undefined behavior, you're not guaranteed to get an error and your program may appear to work fine.

Comment: Next time, use `std::cout`, thus learning how to properly implement an `operator  <<` for your `Simple` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function, which means it does not know how to check the types of the second and following arguments. Therefore, in a typical implementation it trusts that you are giving it arguments of the correct type as indicated by the `%d`, i.e. `int`. Your `sim` object, in memory, is three `ints` packed together. `printf`, given the `%d`, attempts to read an `int` and gets the first `int` variable you declared in `sim`.

Please note that this is undefined behavior and you should not rely on it.

Comment: This make sense. Infact if I write printf("%d%d%d\n", sim);, I have "321".

Comment: @VFG • just more undefined behavior, which may vary from compiler to compiler, or depending on what compiler optimizes are enabled.

Comment: @VFG anyway this is not guaranty, just define the operator<< on your class

Comment: @VFG No. That code you now wrote is not guaranteed to do anything definite.  It may even crash the program if you tried it on a different compiler or used different compiler options.

Comment: @JoshWilson "*printf is a variadic function, which means it does not know how to check the types of the second and following arguments*" - many modern compilers provide parameter validation for printf-style functions at compile-time to ensure valid parameters are being passed in based on the format string, if a compile-time string literal is used.